How do you use the Mouse Position Node for Geometry Node Tools?
I am once again playing with Geometry Node Tools. This time, I'm trying to figure out how to use the Mouse Position Node.

According to the manual, the Mouse Position Node outputs pixel quantities as scalar integers. Where is the mouse cursor located in 3D space?
In an attempt to use this node, I tried to recreate Ctrl+RMB (Add a vertex) from Edit mode. The vertices did not line up to where the mouse cursor was.

For testing, I incorporated the camera into my node tree to visualize where my mouse cursor was. However, I seriously could not picture where the mouse cursor was located from my viewport nor was I able to make sense of the values given by the Mouse Position Node.

Does anyone know how to use this node?

Blender 4.3.2


That was quite hard to figure out given the documentation is incredibly poor on what "projection" and "view" mean, but finally:
With the given configuration of transforms, you can turn -1,-1 to bottom left and +1,+1 to top right of the view.
All you need is to map the pixel values to something between -1 and +1.


Amazing! I never liked the manual. It's way too vague and lacks any useful examples.
